# Should I upgrade from LTS to another LTS ember version?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've been trying to upgrade my ember app from `2.18` to `3.4.4` and I just want to know if I chose the correct ember version which is `3.4.4`? Any response is much appreciated. Also what are the disadvantages or issues I may face if I jump from `2.18` to `3.8.1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal recommendation is to upgrade from one LTS to the next LTS version. There's a great [video from Ember Map](https://embermap.com/video/how-to-upgrade-an-ember-app-or-addon) that discusses a great strategy for upgrading your ember apps which I will summarize here in case the link ever goes stale.

> 1. Upgrade all forwards-compatible packages
> 2. Upgrade 3rd-party dependencies and addons, one at a time
> 3. Upgrade Ember CLI and friends using ember-cli-update

And in my opinion, use `ember-cli-update --to next-lts-version-here`. Once you upgrade to the LTS, fix deprecations and tests until all green, and then continue. I used this process to go from 2.16 -> 3.8 over the weekend

Answer (score 1):

The latest long term support is 3.8. here is release [cycle](https://emberjs.com/builds/). You can jump to 3.8 if suits you.
There is a addon named [ember-cli-update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-update). It applies changes automatically. Also you can [checkout](https://www.emberjs.com/blog/) the ember-blog to learn changes.